# regarding Static memory leak

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have class named `LineInfo` in some other class I'm allocating it and using the object of that class I'm allocating memory to some array then how to release that array for example in class B:

```
A *a=[[A alloc]init];  
a.lineArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:_xElements];   
[a release];
```

now I'm releasing a (`[a release]`),but in static analyzer still its giving leak with `linearray`. How can I release it?

Answer (score 1):

If `lineArray` is a retained property of your 'A' class, then assigning it an allocated object should throw a memory leak. If so, instead if the following line;

```
a.lineArray=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:_xElements];
```

try the following,

```
NSMutableArray *tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:_xElements];
a.lineArray = tempArray;
[tempArray release];
```

Answer (score 1):

`lineArray` is probably a retained property on the class A, so when you assign it you should do an autorelease:

```
a.lineArray=[[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithArray:_xElements] autorelease];
```

or better:

```
a.lineArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: _xElements];
```

Then you need to release lineArray in the dealloc method of A.

```
- (void)dealloc
{
  [lineArray release];

  [super dealloc];
}
```